# Create IExternalSignature with x509Certificate2 in C# and iText 7

Tags: c#, itext, primary-key, sign, x509certificate2

I am testing the iText 7.1.2.0 library to sign pdf files, using a digital certificate or smart card (X509Certificate2) in a C # project. But I'm getting this error when I try to create the IExternalSignature.

[image]

According to the documentation found ([here](https://pages.itextpdf.com/rs/204-LXA-936/images/digitalsignatures20130304.pdf?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTmpCaVlXUTJaRGxrWkRBNSIsInQiOiJCU21BY20zWDhLbE5haHBZM2FMQUxvWFVXTjQ1dkJoS21hcjAyNDFzZUdKd25pVTdlUWkwRzM1SlwvVUFsRXljSVJBZnh3MVwvXC82YUUyTFE3YjdlVWVWVSsrejNXWXkrWE4zMUlsSld3UDlWK3JQVXkyVHBINVFlMXBUcDBGb2ZqbSJ9), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997118/how-do-i-sign-a-pdf-document-using-a-certificate-from-the-windows-cert-store) and [here](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.5/com/itextpdf/signatures/package-summary.html)), the way to achieve this process is using the BouncyCastle library that allows extracting the primary keys from the digital certificate, however, it is giving me an error and I can not find another way to do it.
In the documentation ([here](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7NS/repos/samples/browse/itext/itext.publications/itext.publications.signatures/itext/samples/signatures/chapter03/C3_01_SignWithCAcert.cs)) they are created from .pfx files, but for this case, I need to take the primary keys directly from the certificate in the card reader. In previous versions of iText, it's allowed the creation with the following command:

```
IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(Certificate, "SHA-1");
```

But in version 7 it is no longer available and in the documentation I do not see how to do it.

Someone has used iText 7 and has been able to sign using an X509Certificate2 that knows the correct way to create the IExternalSignature?

This is the code that I am using:

```
public void SignPDF(string source, string target, X509Certificate2 certificate, string reason, string location, bool addVisibleSign, bool addTimeStamp, string strTSA, int qtySigns, int pageNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate vert = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certificate);

            X509CertificateParser objCP = new X509CertificateParser();
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] objChain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { objCP.ReadCertificate(certificate.RawData) };

            IList<ICrlClient> crlList = new List<ICrlClient>();
            crlList.Add(new CrlClientOnline(objChain));

            PdfReader objReader = new PdfReader(source);
            PdfSigner objStamper = new PdfSigner(objReader, new FileStream(target, FileMode.Create), false);

            ITSAClient tsaClient = null;
            IOcspClient ocspClient = null;

            if (addTimeStamp)
            {
                OCSPVerifier ocspVerifier = new OCSPVerifier(null, null);
                ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(ocspVerifier);
                tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(strTSA);
            }

            PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = objStamper.GetSignatureAppearance();
            signatureAppearance.SetReason(reason);
            signatureAppearance.SetLocation(location);
            signatureAppearance.SetPageNumber(pageNumber);
            signatureAppearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);

            if (addVisibleSign && qtySigns == 1)
                signatureAppearance.SetPageRect(new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(36, 20, 144, 53)).SetPageNumber(pageNumber);
            else if (addVisibleSign && qtySigns == 2)
                signatureAppearance.SetPageRect(new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(160, 20, 268, 53)).SetPageNumber(pageNumber);
            else if (addVisibleSign && qtySigns == 3)
                signatureAppearance.SetPageRect(new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(284, 20, 392, 53)).SetPageNumber(pageNumber);
            else if (addVisibleSign && qtySigns == 4)
                signatureAppearance.SetPageRect(new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(408, 20, 516, 53)).SetPageNumber(pageNumber);

            var pk = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(certificate.PrivateKey).Private;

            IExternalSignature externalSignature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-1");
            objStamper.SignDetached(externalSignature, objChain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);

            if (objReader != null)
            {
                objReader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.error = true;
            result.errorMessage += "Error: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I do not believe that class was ported to iText 7- it is just a wrapper class.

You can see how to create a custom IExternalSignatureContainer in [this example](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/signatures/browse/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter04/C4_09_DeferredSigning.java#55-#85)

Note that the source for the iText 5 X509Certificate2Signature can be found [here](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5N/repos/itextsharp/browse/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/security/X509Certificate2Signature.cs?at=refs/heads/develop)

So something like this:

```
public class X509Certificate2Signature: IExternalSignature {
    private String hashAlgorithm;
    private String encryptionAlgorithm;
    private X509Certificate2 certificate;

    public X509Certificate2Signature(X509Certificate2 certificate, String hashAlgorithm) {
        if (!certificate.HasPrivateKey)
            throw new ArgumentException("No private key.");
        this.certificate = certificate;
        this.hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.GetDigest(DigestAlgorithms.GetAllowedDigest(hashAlgorithm));
        if (certificate.PrivateKey is RSACryptoServiceProvider)
            encryptionAlgorithm = "RSA";
        else if (certificate.PrivateKey is DSACryptoServiceProvider)
            encryptionAlgorithm = "DSA";
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown encryption algorithm " + certificate.PrivateKey);
    }

    public virtual byte[] Sign(byte[] message) {
        if (certificate.PrivateKey is RSACryptoServiceProvider) {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) certificate.PrivateKey;
            return rsa.SignData(message, hashAlgorithm);
        }
        else {
            DSACryptoServiceProvider dsa = (DSACryptoServiceProvider) certificate.PrivateKey;
            return dsa.SignData(message);
        }
    }

    public virtual String GetHashAlgorithm() {
        return hashAlgorithm;
    }

    public virtual String GetEncryptionAlgorithm() {
        return encryptionAlgorithm;
    }
}
```

Will replicate the class' function in iText 7. How to use the class is shown [here](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/signatures/browse/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter04/C4_09_DeferredSigning.java#104-#105) in my first link, though you most likely will be using the `signDetached()` method instead of the `signDeffered()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The `certificate.PrivateKey` in my experience is not reliable when you're dealing with non-RSA key pairs. For example a certificate that has an ECDsa key-pair will throw a  `NotSupportedException("The certificate key algorithm is not supported")` on calling `.PrivateKey`, don't know why ([actually here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58866368/6389395), also [probably useful](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17269#issuecomment-218932128)). So I implemented a (little janky) workaround to retrieve the private key, and create an `IExternalSignature` out of it. Since the code has no knowledge of what type of key a certificate has, and I couldn't be bothered to process the other properties to find out, I wrote a loop that tries for a generic, RSA, DSA and ECDsa key extraction. The generic works for RSA too, but since `X509Certificate2`  has a `GetRSAPrivateKey()` method, I made a switch case for it just in case.

```cs
#nullable enable
private (IExternalSignature? signature, IDisposable? key) ExtractPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
  IExternalSignature? signature = null;
  bool foundPk = false;
  int attempt = 0;
  IDisposable? key = null;
  
  while (foundPk is false)
  {
      try
      {
          switch (attempt)
          {
              case 0:
                  AsymmetricAlgorithm? pk = certificate.PrivateKey; //throws exception when certificate has an ECDsa key
                  signature = new PrivateKeySignature(DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(pk).Private, _digestAlgorithm);
                  key = pk;
                  break;
              case 1:
                  RSA rsa = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey() ?? throw new NotSupportedException("RSA private key is null on the certificate.");
                  signature = new PrivateKeySignature(DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(rsa).Private, _digestAlgorithm);
                  key = rsa;
                  break;
              case 2:
                  DSA dsa = certificate.GetDSAPrivateKey() ?? throw new NotSupportedException("Dsa private key is null on the certificate.");
                  signature = new PrivateKeySignature(DotNetUtilities.GetDsaKeyPair(dsa).Private, _digestAlgorithm);
                  key = dsa;
                  break;
              case 3:
                  ECDsa ecdsa = certificate.GetECDsaPrivateKey() ?? throw new NotSupportedException("ECDsa private key is null on the certificate.");
                  signature = new EcdsaSignature(ecdsa, _digestAlgorithm);
                  key = ecdsa;
                  break;
          }
          foundPk = true;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          _logger.LogDebug(e, $"Private key extraction ran into an exception. Attempt (zero-based): {attempt}");
      }

      attempt++;
  }

  if (signature == null)
  {
      throw new NotSupportedException(
          $"The private key of the certificate could not be retrieved for signing. {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(certificate.SubjectName)}");
  }

  return (signature, key);
}
```

As you can see iText 7 has a handy utilities class, that contains a lot of util functions ported from the Java version, but for some reason only a lot, and not all of them. It doesn't support ECDsa key pairs, so I had to implement my own version of that. For completeness that class is included below.

```cs
#nullable enable
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using iText.Signatures;
public class EcdsaSignature : IExternalSignature
{
    private readonly string _encryptionAlgorithm;
    private readonly string _hashAlgorithm;
    private readonly ECDsa _pk;
    private const string EcdsaEncryptionAlgorithm = "ECDSA";

    public EcdsaSignature(ECDsa? pk, string hashAlgorithm)
    {
        _pk = pk ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pk), "ECDSA private key cannot be null.");
        _hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.GetDigest(DigestAlgorithms.GetAllowedDigest(hashAlgorithm));
        _encryptionAlgorithm = EcdsaEncryptionAlgorithm;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     <inheritDoc />
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string GetEncryptionAlgorithm()
    {
        return _encryptionAlgorithm;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     <inheritDoc />
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string GetHashAlgorithm()
    {
        return _hashAlgorithm;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     <inheritDoc />
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     <see href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/67255440/6389395"> RFC 5480 format.</see>
    /// </remarks>
    public virtual byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
    {
        return _pk.SignData(message, new HashAlgorithmName(_hashAlgorithm), DSASignatureFormat.Rfc3279DerSequence);
    }
}
```

Also note that the `ExtractPrivateKey()` method returns the key as an `IDisposable` as well, this is so it can be disposed of after the signature is done. I could have made a public property in `EcdsaSignature`, but iText's own `IExternalSignature`s don't expose the PK either, so neither should I.