# iText7 and C# - X509Certificate2Signature port can't sign using RSAcng

Tags: rsa, digital-signature, itext7

I'm trying to sign a PDF using iText7 the way I did with iText5:

- I took the Cert from Windows Personal Store.
- I create an IExternalSignature based on the Cert.

I found that X509Certificate2Signature class is not present in iText7.

Because of that I've ported it, however when the Signer method SignDetached is invoked I get that nasty error telling that the classic RSA algorithm is not available because now it is a bit different (RSAcng).

Is there a workaround?

For sure, there must be a reason why the class was not ported to iText7 that I can't understand.

Thanks.

Comment: If you showed your `X509Certificate2Signature` port, we might help pointing out problems.

Comment: Thanks.
Here is the part that raises the error:

Comment: public X509Certificate2Signature(X509Certificate2 certificate, String hashAlgorithm)
        {
            if (certificate.PrivateKey is System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider)
                encryptionAlgorithm = "RSA";
            else if (certificate.PrivateKey is System.Security.Cryptography.DSACryptoServiceProvider)
                encryptionAlgorithm = "DSA";
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown encryption algorithm " + certificate.PrivateKey);
        }

Comment: X509Certificate2 class encryption algorithm is RSACng instead of RSA.

Comment: So, there is no RSACng Crypto Service Provider class to get things done in System.Security.Cryptography.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50627483/1520650